# How to make own local package importable the same way as pip installed packages?

Tags: anaconda

How can I save my own package to conda environment so it is importable from any location once environment is activated?

When we `conda activate my_env` and  `pip install package` the `package` can be imported no matter what the location of `file.py` is. What can I do to have my `own_local_package` importable the same way once `my_env` is activated?

Comment: What do you mean by _no matter what the location of file.py is._ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pip` locally to install packages, and use `import mypackage` the same way you do with any other module, the correct approach is to :

`python -m pip install -e /path_to_package/mypackage/`

- `python -m` ensures you are using the pip package from the same `python` installation you are currently using.
- `-e` makes it editable, i/e `import mypackage` will reload after you make some changes, instead of using the cached one.

`mypackage` must contain an `__init__.py`
file, and a basic `setup.py` (or `pyproject.toml` file for `pipenv`)

**the package structure** must be like this:

```
mypackage/
    setup.py
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
```

**minimal `setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',              # Required
    version='0.0.1',           # Required
    packages=find_packages(),  # Required
)
```

---

#### for a more elaborate package:

**the package structure** must be like this:

```
mypackage/
    setup.py
    mypackage/
        src/
            __init__.py
            __main__.py
            additional python files
            ...
```

**minimal `setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='mypackage',                          # Required
    version='0.0.1',                       # Required
    packages=find_packages(where="/src"),  # Required
)
```